# Symfony2 voters for entire entity permissions

Tags: php, symfony

We are setting up Roles in our platform, some of this roles (`ROLE_VISITOR`, `ROLE_REGISTERED`) have permissions

`CREATE_BLOG_POST`, `CREATE_BLOG_COMMENT`

Theese permissions can be true or false, but as we don't want them as new Roles, but permissions, we should use Voters. An user can also have both permissions, or none.

We want to allow/disallow our users to create a blog post or a blog comment, whenever they are allowed or not, but as Voters works on individual items from an entity (Owner or not owner), I don't know how to continue.

We want total control over CRUD for an entire entity depending on the permission.

I am not showing any of my code because I've tried only what DOC says...http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/cookbook/security/voters.html but I would like some advice or example code in order to achieve this.

I hope I've explained everything.

Comment: Having trouble understanding the question.  You want some users to be able to create blogs but not other users?  You don't want to assign CREATE_BLOG_POST roles to users?  While normally a voter works on an individual entity it does not have to.  You can pass a null entity and just have to voter decide if a given user can create a post using whatever criteria you want.

Comment: Kind of. I don't want to create a role, I want permissions, because two roles can have same permissions so hierarchy won't work as wanted. Maybe I should use a permissions entity or field in user entity and then compare it inside my voter against my criteria? I hope there is a way to handle real permissions for an entire class, not an item from a class.

Comment: I would use groups, assign roles/permissions/whatever you want to call them to the groups, then give the user a group/s. I think youre making it more complicated than it needs to be...

Comment: Well it's not my decision... Product Manager's. Assign group for permissions isn't something they want. A group is "Blog Commentors" or "Blog Poster" but, i forgot to mention in my question, a user can have both, can Post and Comment in blog...

Answer (score 1):

Here you have an example without other entity :

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Voters;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\Voter\VoterInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

class BlogVoter  implements VoterInterface
{
    const CREATE_BLOG_COMMENT = 'create_blog_comment';   
    const CREATE_BLOG_POST = 'create_blog_post';     

    public function vote(TokenInterface $token, $object, array $attributes)
    {    
        $user = $token->getUser();

        $supports = false;
        foreach($attributes as $attribute){
            if(in_array($attribute,array(self::CREATE_BLOG_COMMENT,self::CREATE_BLOG_POST))){
                $supports = true;
            }
        }

        if(!$supports){
            return self::ACCESS_ABSTAIN;
        }

        if ($user instanceof UserInterface) {
            $roles = $user->getRoles();

            switch($attribute) {
                case self::CREATE_BLOG_COMMENT:
                    if(in_array('ROLE_VISITOR',$roles)|| in_array('ROLE_REGISTERED',$roles)){
                        return self::ACCESS_GRANTED;
                    }
                break;
                case self::CREATE_BLOG_POST:
                    if(in_array('ROLE_REGISTERED',$roles)){
                        return self::ACCESS_GRANTED;
                    }
                break;
            }
        }

        return self::ACCESS_DENIED;
    }
}
```